# PHP empty() error message

Tags: php

I have just started learning and have put together the form below. The confusion I have is when I use empty to validate if the user selected or entered any information, the code generates the error below.

I noticed if I have the following lines of code

```
if(empty($gender)) {
        $errormessage[2] = "Please select your gender";
    }
```

as

```
if(empty($_POST["gender"])) {
        $errormessage[2] = "Please select your gender";
    }
```

and

```
if(empty($gender)) {
        $errormessage[2] = "Please select your gender";
    }
```

as

```
if(empty($_POST["gender"])) {
        $errormessage[2] = "Please select your gender";
    }
```

I do not see the error message. I take it that error message is being generated because of the lines of code $_POST for the gender and media form elements which are radio buttons and checkboxes respectively. However if I want to initialize all the variables at the top, what is the best way to do so?

```
/* <?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $fname = $_POST["fname"];
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];
    $gender = $_POST["gender"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $media = $_POST['media'];

    $errormessage =  array();

    if(empty($fname)) {
        $errormessage[0] = "Please enter your first name";
    }

    if(empty($lname)) {
        $errormessage[1] = "Please enter your last name";
    }

    if(empty($gender)) {
        $errormessage[2] = "Please select your gender";
    }

    if(empty($age)) {
        $errormessage[3] = "Please select your age";
    }

    if(empty($address)) {
        $errormessage[4] = "Please enter your address";
    }

    if(empty($media)) {
        $errormessage = "Please select the type of media";

    }

}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Sample registration</h4>
        <form name="registration" method="post" action="registration.php">
            <div>
                First Name: <br />
                <input type="text" name="fname" value="">
            </div>

            <div>
                Last Name: <br />
                <input type="text" name="lname" value="">
            </div>

            <div>
                Gender: <br />
                male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
                female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
            </div>

            <div>
                Age: <br />
                <select name="age">
                    <option value="">Please select your age</option>
                    <option value="18-25">18-25</option>
                    <option value="26-33">26-33</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div>
                Address: <br />
                <textarea name="address" cols="10" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div>
                Sign-me up: <br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="media['newsletter']" value="newsletter"> newsletter
                <input type="checkbox" name="media['specials']" value="specials"> specials
                <input type="checkbox" name="media['events']" value="events"> events

            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>

*/
```

/* Error Message */

```
! ) Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\registration.php on line 7
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  341792  {main}( )   ..\registration.php:0
Dump $_SERVER

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] =



string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)

$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =



string 'POST' (length=4)

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] =



string '/registration.php' (length=17)

Variables in local scope (#1)

$address =

    Undefined

$age =

    Undefined

$errormessage =

    Undefined

$errormsg =

    Undefined

$fname =



string '' (length=0)

$gender =

    Undefined

$lname =



string '' (length=0)

$media =

    Undefined

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: media in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\registration.php on line 10
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  341792  {main}( )   ..\registration.php:0
Variables in local scope (#1)

$address =



string '' (length=0)

$age =



string '' (length=0)

$errormessage =

    Undefined

$errormsg =

    Undefined

$fname =



string '' (length=0)

$gender =



null

$lname =



string '' (length=0)

$media =

    Undefined
```

Comment: where are you expecting the error message to show? I don't see where you are trying to display the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to check whether those `$_POST['gender']` and `$_POST['media']` variables were actually set in the HTTP POST request before you go accessing them; a better solution to initialize each `$_POST` var might be something like this:

`$fname = isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';`

The above ternary assignment is equivalent to running the following logical expression for every single `$_POST` variable in which you're interested:

```
if( isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ) {
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
} else {
    $fname = '';
}
```

If you implement either of these, you won't get a notice if you run `empty()` on `$gender`; furthermore, if `$_POST['gender']` wasn't set, `empty()` will still behave the way you expect. It adds a little verbosity, but to rewrite your example you might try:

```
if( isset( $_POST["submit"] ) ) {

    $fname = isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ? $_POST["fname"] : '';
    $lname = isset( $_POST['lname'] ) ? $_POST["lname"] : '';
    $gender = isset( $_POST['gender'] ) ? $_POST["gender"] : '';
    $age = isset( $_POST['age'] ) ? $_POST["age"] : '';
    $address = isset( $_POST['address'] ) ? $_POST["address"] : '';
    $media = isset( $_POST['media'] ) ? $_POST['media'] : '';

    $errormessage =  array();
    if( empty( $fname ) )
        $errormessage[] = "Please enter your first name";
    if( empty( $lname ) )
        $errormessage[] = "Please enter your last name";
    if( empty( $gender ) )
        $errormessage[] = "Please select your gender";
    if( empty( $age ) )
        $errormessage[] = "Please select your age";
    if( empty( $address ) )
        $errormessage[] = "Please enter your address";
    if( empty( $media ) )
        $errormessage[] = "Please select the type of media";
}
```

Of course, you'd want to clean your data if you're going to use it in a SQL context, but that should at least get you around the error you're facing.

If you had a lot of these variables--or were repeating this task often--you might consider rolling it up into a function!

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Considering I am new to the world of PHP, I am yet to learn about functions especially custom functions. Furthermore, I don't quite follow your example as I have no idea what ? does as well as : ''; in the code example of  $fname = isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ? $_POST["fname"] : '';. Would you mind elaborating what it is and does and when I would use it?

Comment: Sure! the ?: you see there is the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in PHP and it works like this: `(condition ? "true!" : "false!")` for the entire expression enclosed in parentheses, if `condition` evaluates to true, then the whole expression evaluates to `"true!"`; otherwise, the whole expression evaluates to `"false!"`--it's really just a shortcut for if(){}else{} if you want to think of it that way

Comment: Sorry. I still don't follow. What is the condition in the code above? What are we testing as true or false?

Comment: In this code: `$b = true; $val = ( $b ? "yes" : "no" );`, `$val == "yes"`, but in this code: `$b = false; $val = ( $b ? "yes" : "no" );`, `$val == "no"`. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes it does at a very high level. Let me break it down and correct me if I am wrong. I'll use the code I was working on.  $fname = ($_POST["gender"] = true ? "yes" : "no"); $fname == "yes". Is that correct? I don't still follow how this is similar with the example you gave. Sorry if I am not following as quickly.

Comment: `$fname = isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ? $_POST["fname"] : '';` breaks down like this: first, `$fname` is going to be assigned the value of whatever the right-hand side of the equation evaluates to. Let's figure out what that is! `isset( $_POST['fname'] )` is the `condition` in the ternary operator. If `isset( $_POST['fname'] )` evaluates to `true` (if that variable was actually passed via HTTP POST to the page), then the entire expression evaluates to `$_POST['fname']`, the actual value, and this will be saved in `$fname`. Otherwise, the expression evaluates to `''`, an empty string.

Comment: You might also find [this wikipedia write-up on ternary operators in PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Perl.2C_PHP) useful

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I lost you at then the entire expression evaluates to $_POST['fname']. When you say entire expression, what would this me? Also I take it that the actual value would be the data entered in the form if any was entered. Not sure what you meant by this will be saved in $fname. What is this?

Comment: How about this: if `isset( $_POST['fname'] )` evaluates to true (if `fname` was defined in the HTTP POST request), then the _entire expression_ `( isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ? "yes!" : "no!" )` evaluates to `"yes!"`. If `isset( $_POST['fname'] )` evaluates to false (it was never defined in the HTTP POST request), then the _entire expression_ `( isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ? "yes!" : "no!" )` evaluates to `"no!"`. Since you have `$fname` on the left-hand side of the equals sign, its value will be whatever `( isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ? "yes!" : "no!" )` evaluates to--either `"yes!"` or `"no!"`

Comment: Eureka, then makes so much more sense. Thanks so much for your help and patience. So effectively I could write the variable as '$fname = ( isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ? "yes!" : "no!" )'. I am guessing the expression '$fname = isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ? $_POST["fname"] : ''' is shorthand. 

I still don't quite follow it because of 'isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ? $_POST["fname"]' as the example above is 'isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ? "yes!" : "no!"'

Comment: i would read the lines in my _answer_ aloud as: "the variable `$fname` should be set to the value of `$_POST['fname']` as long as `$_POST['fname']` is actually set; otherwise, it should be set to a blank string". i'm hoping that helps and that all of this has answered your question!! :] setting it to a blank string helps later on if you want to use `empty( $fname )`, since `empty('')` is `true`.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh!!!. Think I got it. The expression isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ? $_POST["fname"] : '' means that if isset( $_POST['fname'] ) has  a value then that value is $_POST["fname"]. If it has not value then it is blank i.e. ''. Is that right?

Comment: almost! _if_ `$_POST['fname']` is set, then assign the value of `$_POST['fname']` to `$fname`; otherwise, assign `''` to `$fname`. remember, the ultimate goal of the ternary operation is the assign something to the _left-hand_ side, or `$fname`. the right-hand side is just a way to decide _what_ to assign.

Comment: you could also write the whole thing this way (forgive the lack of linebreaks): `if ( isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ){ $fname = $_POST['fname']; } else { $fname = ''; }`

Comment: Wohoo. Finally I get it. Thanks so much Ryan. It finally makes sense. Sorry it took a while to get there.

Comment: no worries! i love ternary operations, but they're definitely confusing at first. i updated my answer itself with the important stuff from this comment thread, in case you want to reference it in the future!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `!isset()` instead of `empty()`.

As a side-note, the way you're assigning your variables will create `warning` notices if that `$_POST` value doesn't exist. If you'd like to remove those notices, use @Ryan's solution.

Comment: Why would I use !isset when my understanding is that all I am saying that if isset is not true, then return error message. I know that the elements are not set and returning a NULL value (I think), hence I am using empty() unless I have misunderstood the use of isset.

Comment: **Example:** if `$_POST['blah']` doesn't exist in `$_POST`, then `$var = $_POST['blah']` will fail and `$var` will not be set to anything.

Comment: Ok, if it not set to anything them empty should be able to capture the failure. Is that not right?

Comment: Technically yes, but you're still generating `warning` notices. They're not fatal, but they add to your error log and can result in unpredictable behavior in your script.